# Odd reference within class behaviour

Tags: python, class, reference

Using Python 2.7, we expect the following code,

```
class T(object):
    def __init__(self,x = list()):
        self.x = x
        self.x.append(0)
        print self.x

a = T()
b = T()
```

to print

> [0]
>
> [0]

However, what actually happens is the following

> [0]
>
> [0, 0]

I am unable to spot why this happen, and how I can prevent this behaviour. It is clear, that [] in the default parameter suddenly becomes a reference to an object shared by all instances of the class... But why? And how can one prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you mean to take a copy of the list rather than a reference to it:

```
self.x = x[:]
```

On top of that, you have fallen foul of the fact that there is a single instance of the default parameter. Which you then modify leading to all sorts of unexpected behaviour. The normal way to deal with that is like this:

```
class T(object):
    def __init__(self, x = None):
        if x is None:
            x = []
        self.x = x[:]
        self.x.append(0)
        print self.x
```

And if you really want a reference to the supplied argument then you can replace `x[:]` with `x` in the above.

Comment: No, the *default argument* is mutable. Which is best solved by not having a default mutable argument in the first place.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I spotted that when I read the code more closely. I still rather imagine that the user intends for a copy to be made